# Print all the possible palindromes that can be generated only moving 1 index

Tags: c++, palindrome

I am trying to do a program which print all possible palindromes that can be generated rearrangement involves that a character changes its position with maximum 1 index, meaning only interchanges of adjacent characters are allowed.

I tried a lot of codes but the best one I had is the next one.

Only I could get all possible palindromes rearranged but with all changes (not only one)

**CODE**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
#define M 26

bool caNformPalindrome(string str, int* count_array)
{
    //Initialize array with zeroes
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        count_array[i] = 0;
    }
    int length = str.length();

    /* Updating frequency according to given string */
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        count_array[str[i] - 'a']++;
    }
    int odd_count = 0;
    //Find odd_count
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if (count_array[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            odd_count++;
        }
    }
    //if length is odd_count then only one letter's frequency must be odd_count
    if ((length % 2 == 1 && odd_count == 1 ) || (length %2 == 0 && odd_count == 0))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else//if length is even no letter should have odd_count frequency
    {
        return false;
    }
}
//Function to reverse the string
string reverse(string str)
{
    string rev = str;
    reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
    return rev;
}

//Function to print 
void printPalIndromes(string str)
{
    int count_array[M];
    // checking whether letter can make palindrome or not
    if (!caNformPalindrome(str, count_array))
    {
        return;
    }
    int length = str.length();

    // half will contain half part of all palindromes,
    // that is why pushing half count_array of each letter
    string half = "";
    char mid;//store odd count charcter
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        if(count_array[i] % 2 == 1)
        {
            mid = i + 'a';
        }
        half += string(count_array[i] / 2, i + 'a');
    }
    string palindrome_string;
    do
    {
        palindrome_string = half;
        if (length % 2 == 1)
        {
            palindrome_string += mid;
        }
        palindrome_string += reverse(half);
        cout<<palindrome_string<<endl;
    }
    while (next_permutation(half.begin(), half.end()));
}

//Main function
int main()
{
    string str = "aabbc";
    cout<<"Possible Permutations for Input_string only with 1 change"<<str<<" are: "<<endl;
    printPalIndromes(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are only `n-1` swaps for a string of length `n`. Try all `n` swaps and see which ones are palindromes.

Comment: Why do all that work even?   There is at most one.  Just iterate forward from front and backward from rear until you find non-matching characters.  Then check just one character more and reject the string if it doesn't match.   Continue as if the transpose occurred otherwise (you don't even have to do the next-character check after the first swap).